# Unix concatenation commands

Tags: unix, pipe, cat

I've got a question here that I dont understand:

```
cat abc.dat | tee bcd.dat | tr ab ba > cde.dat
```

In this instance, I understand the translate part, but I’m a little confused as to what the pipe | does, I’ve been told that it takes the stdout of a program with the stdin of another. If I were to try to explain this, correct me if I’m wrong but you’re taking abc.dat’s contents, duplicating the output into bcd.dat, and then taking the content from bcd.dat and translating instances of a and b into b and a respectively, and then taking that and putting it into cde.dat?

The official answer is: abc.dat is copied to bcd.dat. and abc.dat is copied to cde.dat but with 'a’ replaced by 'b' and 'b‘ replaced by 'a'. But why is abc.dat copied into cde.dat instead of bcd.dat? does the pipe not continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "official" answer is poorly worded. Neither `tee` nor `tr` know anything about `abc.dat`; it just happens that what it reads from `tee` is what `tee` read from `cat`, which is what `cat` read from `abc.dat`.

Comment: soooooo...my explanation was right?

Comment: Close. Nothing reads from `bcd.dat`, but the standard output of `tee` (which `tr` reads from) is identical to what is written to `bcd.dat`.

Comment: ohhh that makes sense. so after the creation of bcd nothing actually happens to it, and it's never referenced again. In short, the tee function produces not only a stdout but also a duplicate of what was taken in (which are not the same things), right?

Comment: Right; it writes to standard output as well as any file whose name is passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `tee` utility reads from stdin and writes this firstly to stdout, **and** secondly to *all* files given as argument. In your case, stdin is written to stdout, and to file `bcd.dat`. The pipe behind the `tee` links the stdout of `tee` to the stdin of the `tr`. Although the data is the same, it is not the content of file `bcd.dat` that is being piped to `tr`. It is the output of the initial `cat`, which in turn is the content of file `abc.dat`.